# In Plotly is there a way to increase the number of simultaneous hover values?

Tags: python, hover, plotly, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a plot that contains 6 values.  When I hover, it only displays 5, however.  I want it to display 6 values.  I'm guessing the maximum value is 5.
1) Is my guess right, or is it something else?
2) If my guess is right, is there a way to set it to be greater than 5?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: And what you see in Plotly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a limit, but Plotly will only show a certain number of labels based on the height of the div. I've found that increasing the height displays more hover values.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4acvue2/

Notice that changing the height, changes how many labels display.

You can test this with something like this:

```js
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');

var lines = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 lines.push({
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
  });
}
Plotly.plot( TESTER, lines, { 
    margin: { t: 0 } } );

/* Current Plotly.js version */
console.log( Plotly.BUILD );
```

```html
  <head><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>
<!-- Plots go in blank <div> elements. 
    You can size them in the plot layout,
    or give the div a size as shown here.
-->
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Plotly's Examples for Hover https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/:

In the trace object you can `'<text><{}>'.format(<value(s)>)` for both the `text` and `name`. In the `<text>` you can likely insert a `\n` for a new line if you want that as well.

```
trace0= go.Scatter(
        x= data['rank'],
        y= data['pop']+(i*1000000),
        mode= 'markers',
        marker= dict(size= 14,
                    line= dict(width=1),
                    color= c[i],
                    opacity= 0.3),
        name= y[i],
        text= data['state'] # The hover text goes here... 
                   )
```

Hopefully this helps